# Enable Controls - Colour stripping issue

Tags: vba, colors, ms-word, background-color

I currently have a couple of checkboxes performing the below code.

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Dim en As Boolean
    en = CheckBox2.Value
    EnableControls Array(CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6, CheckBox7, CheckBox9, CheckBox10, CheckBox11, TextBox1), en

End Sub

Private Sub EnableControls(cons, bEnable As Boolean)
    Dim con
    For Each con In cons
        With con
            .Enabled = bEnable
            .BackColor = IIf(bEnable, vbWhite, RGB(240, 240, 240))
        End With
    Next con
End Sub
```

So when Checkbox=False the other checkbox fields are greyed out and you are unable to check them. However, once they are ungreyed out their whole back colour goes from the default "form background grey" to a bold white - any ideas on how to just grey the boxes out and when they are 'un-greyed' they just go back to their default colour????

Comment: That vbWhite setting works for textboxes, but clearly it's not the right value for checkboxes - you will need to swap it out for a different color.

Comment: Can I have multiple  `Private Sub EnableControls(cons, bEnable As Boolean)` lines though? I Need the colour to be white for the textbox fields but then grey for the checkbox fields - and I did a quick check but I don't think I can get a vbGrey :P any suggestions ? @TimWilliams

Comment: You can check what type of control you're working with using `TypeName(con)` and then use that to decide what color you need.

Comment: Default BackColor of Userform is `&H8000000F&` (Button Face). Play with `?hex(userform1.CheckBox1.BackColor)` in immediate window.

Comment: After some testing, leave your code as-is and set your checkboxes' `BackStyle` to `fmBackStyleTransparent` in the form designer.

Comment: @TimWilliams back at it again! hahah aw man - do you do lessons or anything? teach me what you know please haha. awesome.

Comment: @TimWilliams can you add your last comment as an answer so I can select it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little testing shows you can leave your code as-is and set your checkboxes' `BackStyle` to `fmBackStyleTransparent` in the form designer